# Does the morphological analysis of complex words acknowledge/allow multiple derivations?

Tags: morphology, morphological-analysis

I have been watching videos in Youtube concerning the morphological composition of complex words, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQKJNBAbYqM. Phrase structure (as opposed to dependency structure) is assumed for the analyses. My exposure to this art so far suggests that something important is being overlooked. Some complex words should allow multiple derivations, e.g.

[image]

Given that *reuse* and *useable* both exist as independent words, both of these derivations should be possible and allowed. However, the people in the videos do not acknowledge that multiple derivations should be possible or required in certain cases, but rather they are just producing one of the possible derivational analyses.

My question concerns this apparent oversight. Experienced morphologists must be aware of the issue, but do they address it in clear way? Perhaps they simply concede that more than one derivation has to be acknowledged. That strikes me as problematic for the basic approach to the structural analysis of complex words in terms of phrase structure, though. In any case, comments on this matter would be appreciated, especially tips concerning where the issue is addressed directly in the literature. Thanks!

Comment: _Unlockable_ is a better example, because the modal _-able_ and the negative _un-_ interact differently; it's more like a proposition, and that's what trees are for. As for linguists acknowledging the problem, most haven't acknowledged that every written sentence is multiply ambiguous, [as Abney pointed out in 1995](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/abney95c.pdf). And different speakers may differ on their internal structures; maybe some use propositional structures and others don't. Everybody builds their own grammar, after all; there isn't any code book.

Comment: @jlawler. Thanks for the tip. The derivational analysis of _unlockable_ is interesting, but I do not think it would be good to illustrate the point at hand, since it needs distinct derivations to reflect the distinct readings. In contrast, the complex word _reuseable_ is not ambiguous, so there is no reason to choose the one derivational analysis over the other, so it seems that both should be possible. To provide another example, the complex word _irreplaceability_ could be derived in at least four distinct ways even though it is not ambiguous.

Comment: In a neighboring field, Chao Yuen-Ren published, in 1934, his paper on the [*Non-Uniqueness of Phonemic Solutions*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Non-Uniqueness-of-Phonemic-Solutions-of-Systems-Chao/7d862a807cc549133cd13d6cfbc4ff2fad5d4b66) in which he argued that often times, even when working within a certain, narrow framework of assumptions, multiple ways to model facts can be obtained, which should not be dismissed but embraced as different perspectives. My impression is that it was not as widely followed as it should have been.

Comment: @John. Thanks for the tip. I was not aware of the paper you mention. I have Chao's main oeuvre, though. I'll take a look.